# Jhipster Heroku

Tags: jhipster, stderr, heroku-toolbelt

Pristine, updated build. I am able to build and test fine. On "jhipster heroku" I get:

```
  `+ 501 hidden modules
[at-loader] Using typescript@2.3.3 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from C:\puterstuff\jhipster\puterstuff/tsconfig.json.
× { Error: stderr maxBuffer exceeded
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:278:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:548:20) cmd: 'gradlew bootRepackage -x test -Pprod' }`
```

Within the "app\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\heroku\index.js" I added:

```
`maxBuffer: 500*1024`
```

to anywhere I found

```
`...{}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {...`
```

for

```
`...{maxBuffer: 500*1024}, (err, stdout, stderr) => {...`
```

I poked in and around all of the apparent paths and leads...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you followed what has been done in this PR https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6236/commits/dee92a26bc6a82efeedb2ee98700f013a0df6639 or run `jhipster upgrade` to have it as it is included in JHipster 4.7.0

Also, when using `jhpister` CLI, there was a bug which caused to load global version rather than local version from node_modules so your changes were probably not taken into account unless you ran `yo jhipster heroku`, it was fixed also in 4.7.0 by https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6223

So I recommend you upgrade to JHipster 4.7.0